# undefined reference to symbol 'cv::cvtColor(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int)'

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to convert RGB image to Grayscale in ROS, but I am getting the error as below:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/color_to_gray_node.dir/src/color_to_gray.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'cv::cvtColor(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'cv::cvtColor(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int)' is defined in DSO /opt/ros/groovy/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4 so try adding it to the linker command line
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/vincentee/catkin_ws/devel/lib/get_image/color_to_gray_node] Error 1
make[1]: *** [get_image/CMakeFiles/color_to_gray_node.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

below is my CMakelist:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(get_image)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
sensor_msgs
cv_bridge
roscpp
std_msgs
image_transport
)

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
# find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)


## Uncomment this if the package has a setup.py. This macro ensures
## modules and global scripts declared therein get installed
## See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html
# catkin_python_setup()

################################################
## Declare ROS messages, services and actions ##
################################################

## To declare and build messages, services or actions from within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * Let MSG_DEP_SET be the set of packages whose message types you use in
##   your messages/services/actions (e.g. std_msgs, actionlib_msgs, ...).
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend and a run_depend tag for each package in MSG_DEP_SET
##   * If MSG_DEP_SET isn't empty the following dependencies might have been
##     pulled in transitively but can be declared for certainty nonetheless:
##     * add a build_depend tag for "message_generation"
##     * add a run_depend tag for "message_runtime"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "message_generation" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * add "message_runtime" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS ...)
##   * uncomment the add_*_files sections below as needed
##     and list every .msg/.srv/.action file to be processed
##   * uncomment the generate_messages entry below
##   * add every package in MSG_DEP_SET to generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
# add_message_files(
#   FILES
#   Message1.msg
#   Message2.msg
# )

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
# add_service_files(
#   FILES
#   Service1.srv
#   Service2.srv
# )

## Generate actions in the 'action' folder
# add_action_files(
#   FILES
#   Action1.action
#   Action2.action
# )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
# generate_messages(
#   DEPENDENCIES
#   std_msgs  # Or other packages containing msgs
# )

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if you package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES get_image
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS other_catkin_pkg
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
 include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

## Declare a cpp library
# add_library(get_image
#   src/${PROJECT_NAME}/get_image.cpp
# )

## Declare a cpp executable
 add_executable(color_to_gray_node src/color_to_gray.cpp)

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable/library
## as an example, message headers may need to be generated before nodes
# add_dependencies(get_image_node get_image_generate_messages_cpp)

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
 target_link_libraries(color_to_gray_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
#############
## Install ##
#############

# all install targets should use catkin DESTINATION variables
# See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/adv_user_guide/variables.html

## Mark executable scripts (Python etc.) for installation
## in contrast to setup.py, you can choose the destination
# install(PROGRAMS
#   scripts/my_python_script
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark executables and/or libraries for installation
# install(TARGETS get_image get_image_node
#   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark cpp header files for installation
# install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
#   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
#   PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
# )

## Mark other files for installation (e.g. launch and bag files, etc.)
# install(FILES
#   # myfile1
#   # myfile2
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
# )

#############
## Testing ##
#############

## Add gtest based cpp test target and link libraries
# catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}-test test/test_get_image.cpp)
# if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}-test)
#   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ${PROJECT_NAME})
# endif()

## Add folders to be run by python nosetests
# catkin_add_nosetests(test)
```

I'm using ubuntu 12.04, and my ROS opencv version is 2.4.9. I'm also tried to locate libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4, the path show :

```
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4.9
```

I was no idea, Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206333/undefined-reference-to-symbol-%27cv::cvtcolor(cv::_inputarray-const&,-cv::_outputarray-const&,-int,-int)%27/) by [vincentweisen](https://answers.ros.org/users/22039/vincentweisen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-03-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems to me that you don't link to OpenCV. Do this by adding the following line to your CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
```

And you might also need to link your executable/library to it

```
target_link_libraries(your_target ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

In your case change

```
 target_link_libraries(color_to_gray_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

for

```
 target_link_libraries(color_to_gray_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

---

Originally posted by [timster](https://answers.ros.org/users/3358/timster/) with karma: 396 on 2015-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1